# r Counting occurences of specific number between specific number

Tags: r, matrix, frequency

I have a matrix where each element is eather 0 or 1. 
I would like to obtain the frequencies of consecutive occurences of 0's in each row, given the last 0 in the sequence is followed by a 1.

For example:

A row with: 0, 1 , 0, 1, 0, 0

### The expected result should be:

Consecutive 0's of length:  1

Frequency :   2

Another row with:  0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1

### The expected result:

Consecutive 0's of length: 1 2 3

Frequency:  1 1 1

A further objective is then to sum the frequencies of the same length in order to know how many times a single 0 was followed by a 1, two consecutive 0's where followed by a 1 etc.

Here is an exemplary matrix on which I would like to apply the routine:

```
m = matrix( c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,
      1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,
      1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,  0,
      0,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
      1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0,
      1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0),

      ncol = 10, nrow = 6, byrow=TRUE)
```

### The expected result should then be like the matrix below:

```
result = matrix( c(3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ncol=10, nrow=1)
colnames(result) <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
```

Where the column names are the lengths of consecutive 0's (followed by a 1) and the matrix entries the corresponding frequencies.

Note that I have a very large data matrix, and if possible I'd like to avoid loops. Thanks for any hints, comments and propositions.

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the example you showed

Comment: Something like this: `apply(m, 1, rle)`?

Comment: I tried rle() but I think, in this version,  it is difficult to obtain the expected output table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base functions. The complication is you are discarding trailing zeros that do not end with 1.

Explanation in line.

```
set.seed(13L)
numRows <-  10e4
numCols <- 10
m <- matrix(sample(c(0L, 1L), numRows*numCols, replace=TRUE),
    byrow=TRUE, ncol = numCols, nrow = numRows)
#add boundary conditions of all zeros and all ones
m <- rbind(rep(0L, numCols), rep(1L, numCols), m)
#head(m)

rStart <- Sys.time()
lens <- unlist(apply(m, 1, function(x) {
    #find the position of the last 1 while handling boundary condition of all zeros
    idx <- which(x==1)
    endidx <- if (length(idx) == 0) length(x) else max(idx)
    beginidx <- if(length(idx)==0) 1 else min(idx)

    #tabulate the frequencies of running 0s.
    runlen <- rle(x[beginidx:endidx])
    list(table(runlen$lengths[runlen$values==0]))
}))

#tabulating results
res <- aggregate(lens, list(names(lens)), FUN=sum)
ans <- setNames(res$x[match(1:ncol(m), res$Group.1)], 1:ncol(m))
ans[is.na(ans)] <- 0
ans
#     1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10 
#100108  43559  18593   7834   3177   1175    387    103      0    106 

rEnd <- Sys.time()
print(paste0(round(rEnd - rStart, 2), attr(rEnd - rStart, "units")))
#[1] "27.67secs"
```

Do let me know the performance after running on the large matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work. Though the result is surprising me. Ich I apply your code on my small example "m" matrix I get the result:

Comment: if i interpret you correctly, you are typing the values by rows, hence you need to pass in `byrow=TRUE` in your dataset. print `m` in the console to see what matrix you end up with.

Comment: > ans   6  4  1  2  0  0  0  0  0  0 ; which means in the matrix 6 times there was a single 0 followed by a 1 , 4 times two consecutives zeros and so far. However, the result should be like in above in my example.  ( a single 0 is three times followed by a 1, two consecutive 0's followed by a one occurs zero times , three consecutive 0's followed by a 1 occurs one time etc.)

Comment: I run into problems when adding a further condution: zero chains musst not only be followed by a 1, **but also begin after a 1**. Modifying the solution above I run in a problem within the `apply()` command, especially `table()` does not work anylonger:

Comment: Adding in the solution above in `lens` the lines:

Comment: `beginidx <- if(length(idx)==0) length(x) else min(idx)`

Comment: `runlen <- rle(x[(beginidx:endidx)])`

Comment: `table()` runs into problems. What can be the reason?

Comment: Generally, the problem occurs if each line in the m-matrix above begins with a 1: apply the proposed solution on the matrix below:

Comment: m = matrix( c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,
              1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,
              1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,  0,
              1,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
              1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0,
              1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0),
            
            ncol = 10, nrow = 6, byrow=TRUE)

Comment: Hi @Enrico, it should be if(length(idx)==0) 1 else min(idx)

Comment: but still, `table` in the end of `lens` comes into trouble, and `do.call(c, )` cannot be executed.

Comment: hi @Enrico, i do not have any problem running the above code when i change to `beginidx <- if(length(idx)==0) 1 else min(idx); runlen <- rle(x[beginidx:endidx])` maybe you can `print(x[beginidx:endidx])` to see what is causing the problem

Comment: everythin perfectly works, when I check `print(runlen <- rle(x[beginidx:endidx]))`. But running your modified answer I get the error message: `Error in do.call(c, apply(m, 1, function(x) { : 
  the second argument needs to be a list`. This is actually as `table(runlen$lengths[runlen$values==0])` does not output a list. You do not run into this error?

Comment: using the dataset in my post, i do not run into this error.

Comment: True, then there is no error. Only when applying on my exemplary matrix the error occurs. I wished to check the results on that small matrix to be sure that the algo calculates what it actually should do.

Comment: Can you share your dataset?

Comment: `m = matrix( c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,
              1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,
              1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,  0,
              0,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
              1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0,
              1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0),
            
            ncol = 10, nrow = 6, byrow=TRUE)`

Comment: ok have fixed the code as `apply` does not return a list when they are of equal lengths

Comment: thanks a lot for your efforts! Just to render your answer entirely correct for the comunity: with the modification `list(table(runlen$lengths[runlen$values==0]))`, we obtain an error in `res <- aggregate(lens, list(names(lens)), FUN=sum)`: `Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  the arguments need to be of the same length`

Comment: Applying the modification on your large matrix I obtain the error: `res <- aggregate(lens, list(names(lens)), FUN=sum)
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1, 0, 3 `. And the result in `ans` is slightly different with respect of the one you posted in your answer.

Comment: hi @Enrico, i do not get that error when i run my post on a fresh R session

Comment: Good point! Important to take a fresh R session. Well done and thx a lot!